# FeatureCollection 'union' in Google Earth Engine doesn't consider all Features

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometrycollection

Ultimately, what I am trying to do is calculate overlap between (1) polygons of a species' range and (2) polygons of Protected Areas. There can be multiple overlapping polygons for the range (e.g. breeding vs. non-breeding range), so I simply want to perform a union such that there is just one `Feature` made up of multiple polygon geometries (with no overlaps). I tried the following:

```
var spRange = ee.FeatureCollection('users/rasenior/Necrosyrtes_monachus');
var rangeUnion = ee.Feature(spRange.union().first());
```

But when this is mapped as follows:

```
Map.addLayer(spRange, {color: 'blue'}, 'original');
Map.addLayer(rangeUnion, {color: 'green'}, 'union');
```

[image: Output of FeatureCollection union in GEE]

It seems that the union is only a sliver of one tiny section of the overall range. Why?

Possibly related: I've encountered a *lot* of problems for this particular species, which I think might be due to the geometry becoming messy when I upload to GEE. Specifically, one of the features becomes a `GeometryCollection`, containing both `LineStrings` and `Polygons`. I have no idea why, nor how to remove the `LineStrings` (or convert them to `Polygons`?).

Script here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Frasenior%2Ftest%3AgetSpRange

**UPDATE 1:** it's nothing to do with the weird geometry. I have now resolved that issue (use `'users/rasenior/Necrosyrtes_monachus_fix')` such that all geometries are `Polygons` or `MultiPolygons`. But, alas, a union of the `FeatureCollection` still results in the sliver seen in the screenshot.

**UPDATE 2:** now that the `FeatureCollection` is free of weird geometries I was able to export it as a shapefile to inspect in ArcGIS. The `FeatureCollection` is made up of four `Features`, and the green sliver in the screenshot corresponds to the fourth of these. I don't know why this is the only thing being returned by `union`. All I can say is that the fourth `Feature` is the only one with a `Polygon` geometry, whereas the other three `Features` have `MultiPolygon` geometries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in my second update, the problem stems from `union` only considering Polygon Features, and not the MultiPolygon Features.

I solved the problem by combining all Polygons of all geometries into one single MultiPolygon Feature:

```
// Break each feature into constituent geometries
var polyFt = ee.List([spRange
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('geotype', 'Polygon'))
    .geometry()]);
var multiFt = spRange    
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('geotype', 'MultiPolygon'))
    .geometry()
    .geometries();

// Combine all Polygons
var spRangeCombi = ee.FeatureCollection(
    ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(polyFt.cat(multiFt))));
```

For which `union` now works as expected:

```
// Try union again
var spRangeUnion = ee.Feature(spRangeCombi.union().first());
Map.addLayer(spRangeUnion, {color: 'pink'}, 'union');
```

Script [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Frasenior%2Ftest%3AgetSpRange) (same link as in question, now updated).